# FlutterWeb - Display all images in a directory

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm creating a Flutter Web app and i'm trying to figure out a way to display all images in a directory. Here's an example tree.

```
images
- projects
  - p1
    - image1.jpg
    - image2.JPEG
    - image3.png
  - p2
```

I can display every image individually with `Image.Asset(images/projects/p1/image1.jpg)` but some image files have different extensions or are in different subfolders. Since this is flutter web I don't have access to dart:io and cant use Directory() which includes packages like 'path_provider'. Possible solution would be to create a json manifest file with all folders/filenames but some folders can have up to 20-30 files and would require me to update the manifest everytime I add/replace/remove images. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
assets:
    - images/
    - fonts/
```

this way all of the "Direct" child's will be added to the assets but sub-child's won't so if you can make a constant structure for your assets and add only the directories then you don't have to worry about the pubspec.yaml or running `flutter pub get` when files are added or removed .

Comment: Since this is a Flutter Web app you throw your assets in the web folder and load them without using pubspec.yaml. What I want to do is loop through a directory full of images and display them but I don't have access to dart:io for Web apps. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @qrs with directory you mean a directory on your computer or a 'web' directory e.g. a folder which is part of your url?